# Reading a key/value pair to a dictionary by passing the path of the .config file c#

Tags: c#, linq, settings, config

I have two config files, the older version and the newest version.
I need to update the older, so I made the following code to open both and load the key/value into two dictionaries that I will compare later on.
The code is as it follows:
What needs to be changed?

```
 public void UpdateCliente(string FilePathOld, string FilePathNew)
 {
      Dictionary<string, string> Old = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      Dictionary<string, string> New = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      List<string> KeysOld = new List<string>();
      List<string> KeysNew = new List<string>();
      //Keys = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.AllKeys.ToList();

      ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
      configMap.ExeConfigFilename = FilePathOld;
      Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
       KeysOld = config.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys.ToList();

       Old = (config.GetSection("<appSettings>") as System.Collections.Hashtable)
                .Cast<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>()
                .ToDictionary(n => n.Key.ToString(), n => n.Value.ToString());

      //Old = (config.GetSection("<appSettings>") as System.Collections.Hashtable)

  }
```

this line:   `Old = (config.GetSection("<appSettings>") as System.Collections.Hashtable)` gives me the following error:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection' to
>   'System.Collections.Hashtable' via a reference conversion, boxing
>   conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type
>   conversion
>
> NOTE: I forgot the code to convert the keys of the newer file but the
>   method should be the same!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you mean, for example...

```
Configuration config = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = 
    config.AppSettings.Settings;

Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = 
    settings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => settings[key].Value);
```

Also, I think it should be `config.GetSection("appSettings")`

Comment: just a little question. This code will return all the keys in the file? I just have keys in the "appSettings" section

Comment: Returns all in the appSettings

Comment: Ok thank you, actually It doesnt matter since I have to check what keys I can and can't change

Comment: I have an error on the this line:  `Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configOld, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);`
it gives me the following error.
 **An exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll but was not handled in user code**

Comment: Well, maybe you should debug the exception and it's cause :) ?

Comment: that was what I did, and then I got this error, wich I searched in microsoft and couldn't find anything useful :)

Comment: Can't really help w/o reproducing it.

Comment: The code return none key :| what am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: No idea. Put minimal failing example online, then it might be resolved.

Comment: i got the error sorted out, I had a weird code line in my .config file and when I deleted it it was all ok. But now the code runs well but no keys are returned or their value for that matter of speaking

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong types.

[Configuration.GetSection()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.getsection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) returns a `ConfigurationSection` object which is not a `Hashtable`.

The code below should do the trick:

```
var appSettings = config.GetSection("appSettings") as AppSettingsSection;
foreach(var key in appSettings.Settings.AllKeys)
{
    Old[key] = appSettings.Settings[key].Value;
}
```